# How to avoid blink/jump transitions with onEnter hook?

Tags: react-router

I have this issue when using `onEnter` hooks and `replaceState` to redirect the user to another page.

Let's say I have a page that only logged in users can see. This page/route is inside an `onEnter` hook, it will check if the user is logged in or not. If the user is not logged in, it is redirected to a login page (using the `replaceState` function). When the logged out user tries to enter the protected route, sees for an instant (on a blink) the protected page and then redirected to the login page.

How can I avoid this blink?

**EDIT:**
it happens when I use the `callback` provided by the `onEnter` hook.

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar scenario.I solved this by using the `<Redirect/>` component.

```
const Protected = () => {
    <div>Protected Page</div>
}

const RenderProtected = ({ isLoggedin }) -> (
    {isLoggedIn ? <Protected /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
);

<Route exact path="/protected" component={RenderProtected} {...props} />
```

Not sure if this is something that most people follow. I started using the  component after reading [this blog by Tyler McGinnis](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/). I just started digging around with react. Ofcourse, I store the `isLoggedIn` flag somewhere up in the component ladder and pass as props to the child components. I know it's too much but I'm trying not to use Flux for now..